# Can I read discarded post?

Tags: england-and-wales, mail

I am a landlord, and a previous tenant of mine has left the property.  They have left piles of black bags in the rear garden and in the property.  Some of the bags contain letters that have been opened.  Can I read these letters?

Comment: I think jurisdiction is going to be a key factor here. So where are you?

Comment: Are you the landlord, an agent for the landlord, a new tenant or are you just passing by?

Comment: Hi Thanks for responding.  I am the landlord and the property is in Blackpool.

Comment: Are the letters addressed directly to the tenant or are they addressed to "The Occupier". Do you have a reason for reading them besides being nosy?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Torts (Interference with Goods) Act 1977](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1977/32), any possessions left in the property after the tenants have vacated still belongs to the tenant. You are obliged to inform them that they have left some of their possessions behind and you can bill them for any expenses incurred in the disposal of it.

In terms of reading someone else's mail *that has been opened* you may be liable under [article 8 of the Human Rights Act 1998](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1998/42/schedule/1/part/I/chapter/7), since you are possibly accessing your former tenant's personal information without their consent. However, the specifics of the fact that the mail has been abandoned without care does mean that would an interesting legal matter for the courts.

Unless you have a very good reason to read this mail, I would suggest you contact the former tenant informing them that it has been left behind, and if (as is likely) they claim it's just rubbish, then dispose of it and send a bill to them.

Comment: Neither you nor the OP have specified a jurisdiction. Are these acts you cite from Afghanistan or Zimbabwe or one of the other countries in between?

Comment: @DaleM OP specified Blackpool in a comment, hence my edit to the question to add the UK tag.

Comment: @DaleM To pre-empt your "which Blackpool", OP's profile pic is from Blackpool Pleasure Beach. Besides, you **constantly** add the Australian answer to questions with different or unmarked jurisdictions- the only difference is that you have a mod diamond and the qualified immunity that comes with it.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins I confirmed the edit for you but used the england-and-wales tag.

Comment: @Studoku - Even better.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply.  They are addressed to the previous tenant but we have new tenants moving in.  There are a lot of debt agency letters and I want to contact them all to prevent them and/or bailiffs from calling at the property.  But obviously taking their information from the letters 'I am not allowed to read'?

Comment: @SallyNicholsonBradley - Sadly, no. Not within the law. You could warn the new tenant, who will presumably have to deal with debt collection letters or visits intended for the former tenant anyway. But the former tenant could quite possibly take you to court for violating their privacy if you read the letters and acted upon them. I do feel it is unlikely that they would, but it is possible. Any new letters that arrive should be clearly marked "no longer at this address" and put in a postbox.

Comment: That's pants (the laws an ass)!!!  Thanks for taking the time to clarify for me.